# Firefox loses webVTT subtitles when the 'video' tag is 'position: absolute'

Tags: firefox, video, css-position, video-subtitles

Recently I found out that webVTT subtitles which were working properly have dissapeared from the video projection when watching in firefox (currently version 92). Chrome (v 94) shows them without problem.
Apparently the problem must come from the absolute positioning of the 'video' tag, for as soon as I change the position rule to 'relative' or just leave it as it is ('static'), it works.

I have tried defining the position of the subtitles from the VTT file (indicating the % position for every line) to no avail.

¿Does anybody know why this happens? ¿Any solutions NOT involving changing the position definition of the 'video' tag?